# How do I get the name of the class 'a' where class 'b' is created?

Tags: python, django, class, object

I want to do the same that Django does. If I have a Model Poll and a Model Choices and define an attribute `Poll = ForeignKey(Poll)` Poll have a field named `Poll.choices_set`

I have to following code:

```
class rel(object):
    def __init__(self,cls):
        # here I want to get the name of class c there this class is instanced.
        setattr(cls,[name_of_class_c] +"_set",cls())

class a(object):
    pass

class c(object):
    somevar = 3
    relationField = rel(a);

abc = a();
print abc.c_set.somevar
```

Here `class a` is *class Poll*, `class c` is the *Choices class* and `class rel` is the *foreign key class*.

Does somebody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Please update the answer... this looks like a tongue-twister

Comment: I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: This is a black magic called *metaprogramming*. See this: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html Django uses that internally. I advice not going down that road unless you **really** have to. It's difficult to maintain such code. And if you are not sure whether you need it or not, then you don't need it. :)

Comment: But do you know how I can achieve that? A little example for this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to set an attribute, you can just pass the class itself as a parameter:

```
class rel(object):
    def __init__(self,cls, parent):
        setattr(cls,parent.__name__ +"_set",cls())
class c(object):
    somevar = 3
    relationField = rel(a, c);
```

Or if you just want the name:

```
class rel(object):
    def __init__(self,cls, name):
        setattr(cls,name+"_set",cls())
class c(object):
    somevar = 3
    relationField = rel(a, 'c');
```

Comment: But I want to do it the same way django does this, because with django where is no need to pass class c to rel.

Answer (score 0):

Have found a dirty workaround, not perfect yet:

```
class Model:
    pass
class rel(object):
    def __init__(self,cls):
    self.relation = cls;

class a(Model):
    pass

class c(Model):
    some_other = 4
    a = rel(a)

class b(Model):
    somevar = 3
    a = rel(a);

### Some sort of hack ###
gl = list(globals())
for v in gl:
    if type(eval(v)).__name__ == 'classobj':
        cls = eval(v);
        if len(cls.__bases__) > 0 and cls.__bases__[0].__name__ == "Model":
            for atr in dir(cls):
                if type(getattr(cls,atr)).__name__ == "rel":
                    relL = getattr(cls,atr).relation;
                    print relL.__name__, "->", cls.__name__
                    setattr(relL,cls.__name__ + "_set",cls)
### End - Some sort of hack ###

d = a();
print a.b_set.somevar
print a.c_set.some_other
```

Output:

```
a -> c
a -> b
3
4
```

**EDIT:** Some better dirty hack:

```
class Model:
    ### Some sort of hack ###
    def __init__(self):
        gl = list(globals())
        print self.__class__.__name__, "Relations:"
            for v in gl:
                if type(eval(v)).__name__ == 'classobj':
                    cls = eval(v)
                    if len(cls.__bases__) > 0 and cls.__bases__[0].__name__ == "Model":
                        for atr in dir(cls):
                            if type(getattr(cls,atr)).__name__ == "rel":
                                rell = getattr(cls,atr).relation;
                                if isinstance(self,rell):
                                    print rell.__name__, "<-", cls.__name__
                                    setattr(rell,cls.__name__ + "_set",cls)
    ### End - Some sort of hack ###

class rel(object):
    def __init__(self,cls):
    self.relation = cls;

class a(Model):
    pass

class c(Model):
    some_other = 1
    a = rel(a);

class d(Model):
    string = "Hello"
    c = rel(c)
class b(Model):
    somevar = 3
    a = rel(a);
    d = rel(d);


a = a();
c = c();
print "\nVars:"
print "somevar",":",a.b_set.somevar
print "some_other",":",a.c_set.some_other
```

Output:

```
a Relations:
a <- c
a <- b
c Relations:
c <- d
...
```